# write the console output to a text file using jsoup

Tags: java

I wanted to write the console output to a text file but somehow it only writes one line to my text file. I am new  to Java. I don't understand the `p` in the code, so please help me.

Here is my code :

```
package htmlparser;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.*;    
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;    
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.*;

public class Htmlparser {

  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    try {
      String url = "http://cell-phone-providers-review.toptenreviews.com/cingular-review.html";
      Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
      Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
      for(Element p : paragraphs)
        System.out.println(p.text());

      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/Desktop/outputtext.txt")); 
      out.print(System.in); 
      out.close();          
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Htmlparser.class.getName())
            .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: not working. thank you though. it only gives one line "java.io.BufferedInputStream@2e15df3f"

Comment: That's because you are writing the object System.in to the file instead of the text of the paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening your file inside the for loop so only the most recent line gets written as the file is overridden each time.  Open your file outside the for loop and close it after the loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String url = "http://cell-phone-providers-review.toptenreviews.com/cingular-review.html";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/Desktop/outputtext.txt")); 
        for(Element p : paragraphs) {
            out.print(p.text());
        }
        out.close();          
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Htmlparser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried the printwriter outside the loop. still not the expected result.

Comment: What is the output of `print(System.in)` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any braces surrounding your loop so this statement is the only one invoked inside the loop

```
System.out.println(p.text());
```

Create the `PrintWriter` *before* entering the loop and use `out.print(System.in)` to write the console output to file.

Comment: @user3062229 as stated above, create the `PrintWriter` before entering the loop then use `out.print(System.in)` within the loop and remember to add `braces` `{ }`

Comment: Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/Chenfei/Desktop/outputtext.txt")); 
      
      out.print(System.in);
      out.close(); 
      for(Element p : paragraphs)
        System.out.println(p.text());
       
    } is this what you mean?  i am a little confused cause it still didn't give me the expected output.